# JQuery datepicker allow user to set the year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the datepicker jquery plugin with the settings below.

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true 
});
```

Now what i want to do is allowing the user to set the year. I mean by manual changing the input of the selection drop down.

Is there any setting to do that ?

The reason I would like to do that is because I don't know, if the user is selecting a date from the year 1920 or 2220 or what ever year. So I don't have a good default date value. And the dropdown interface isn't that userfriendly if you have to click 20 times to get from the year 2000 to the year 1600.

Edit:
What I want to do is the "Show unlimited years:" from keith-wood.name/datepick.html#monthyear. Is there anything similar with the standard jquery datepicker. I can't find the setting yearRange: 'any' in the jquery datepicker documentation.

Comment: your question is valid. Why did you accept that answer, if it doesn't really solve your needs?!. I'm having the same problem, I'll let you know if I do get to solve this....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
changeYear: true
```

already displaying a selectbox.. so whats the problem??
for manually input of the year just create own input text?

Comment: your edit: i dont want to scroll down a selectbox with unlimited years... create own input field! if you need help with it post again

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. What I would like to do is, that a user can enter the year in the datepicker calender gui. Instead of select the year from a dropdown. I hope this image will help you http://screencast.com/t/kLEUQKRVx

Comment: yes like i said edit it yourself with jquery. get the selectbox of the datepicker and change the attributes... remove the options... make it an input field type text.

Comment: Ah okay now i get it. It seems that I have to do it on my. I'll post the answer when i am finished. Thanks.

Comment: yeah specific things in jquery ui plugins are not easy to change... you need to overwrite css and jquery stuffs. that makes it even harder. dont forget sometimes to look at yui customizer... specially styles can be made there more easily

Answer (score 24):

You can specify a range of years by adding

```
yearRange: "1930:2010"
```

to your attributes. For example:

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     yearRange: "1930:2010"
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-80:+00" // Use this to get the list of years you more than default range.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set year and also month just putting following two lines.

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Here **date** is input ID